# jQuery - How to get the result to overwrite, not duplicate

Tags: jquery

I have a script which suits my needs almost perfectly, you select a color, it changes the color in the DIV by adding inline CSS into the body.

The way it currently works you select a color for pallet one, its adds the inline CSS, you do the same for pallet two, it adds a new style tag for the inline CSS, my issue is if you change pallet one's color again instead of replacing the original CSS it adds another inline-style and so on until you have a heap of style tags.

What have I tried? Nothing because I have no idea where to start, I am learning jQuery and currently have the ability to modify existing scripts and can only get so far.

Here is the jQuery code (fiddle below):

```
function injectStyles(rule) {
      let body = document.querySelector('body');
      let style = document.createElement('style');
      style.textContent = rule;
      body.appendChild(style);
    }

    jQuery(function($) {

      $(".picker").spectrum({
        color: "#ffd800",
        preferredFormat: "hex",
        showInput: true,
        change: function(color) {
          var tiny = tinycolor(color);
          color.getAlpha();
          color.setAlpha(0.8);
          color.getAlpha();
          injectStyles('.testClass  { background:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; color: #fff; border: solid 4px ' + tiny.toHexString() + '}');
        }
      })

      $(".picker2").spectrum({
        color: "#ffd800",
        preferredFormat: "hex",
        showInput: true,
        change: function(color) {
          var tiny = tinycolor(color);
          color.getAlpha();
          color.setAlpha(0.8);
          color.getAlpha();
          injectStyles('.testClass2  { background:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; color: #fff; border: solid 4px ' +               tiny.toHexString() + '}');
        }
      })

    });
```

But you will need to use a few libraries so here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/yp0dx9ou/22/)

Please note that I have simplified my example and the "injectStyles" section of my real project looks like this:

```
 injectStyles('#tab09-1.midBg .bottomBtn:hover, #tab09-1.midBg .homeLinkBtn a:hover, #tab09-2.midBg .bottomBtn:hover, #tab09-2.midBg .homeLinkBtn a:hover, #tab09-3.midBg .bottomBtn:hover, #tab09-3.midBg .homeLinkBtn a:hover, #tab09-4.midBg .bottomBtn:hover, #tab11-4 .eaTest, #tab12-4.midBg .LinkButtons:hover, #tab12-4.midBg .linkbuttons.active, #tab12-4.midBg .linkbuttons:hover, .LinkButtons:hover, .darkBg, .darkBg .LinkButtons:hover, .darkBg .linkbuttons.active, .darkBg .linkbuttons:hover, .linkbuttons.active, .linkbuttons:hover, .midBg .LinkButtons:hover, .midBg .linkbuttons.active, .midBg .linkbuttons:hover, a.expand, button.active, button[type=button]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover { background: ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; color: #fff; } #tab01-2.midBg .searchCon a, #tab07-1.midBg .eaPlan .planbtn a:hover, #tab07-2 .eaPlan, #tab07-3 .eaPlan .planHead, #tab07-4.darkBg .eaPlan .planbtn a, #tab07-4.midBg .eaPlan .planbtn a, #tab09-1 .circleColour, .colDark { background:' + tiny.toHexString() + '; } #tab01-1 .mobFull a, #tab01-1.midBg .mobFull a i, #tab01-2 .mobFull a, #tab01-2.midBg .mobFull a i, #tab01-3 .mobFull a, #tab01-3.midBg .mobFull a i, #tab01-4.midBg .mobFull a i, #tab02-3.greyBg .loginBtn, #tab02-3.whiteBg .loginBtn, #tab06-4.greyBg .eaResInner:hover i, #tab06-4.whiteBg .eaResInner:hover i, #tab07-1 .eaPlan h3, #tab08-1.midBg .newsBtn a, #tab08-1.midBg .newsTitle a, #tab10-1.darkBg h3, #tab10-1.midBg h3, #tab10-3.darkBg h3, #tab10-3.midBg h3, .Header, .SubHeader, .header, .midBg a:hover, .subheader, h1, h3 { color: ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; } #tab01-4 .mobFull a { border: solid 1px #005173; color:' + tiny.toHexString() + '; } #tab01-4.midBg .mobFull a:hover, #tab01 - 4.darkBg.mobFull a: hover { background: #fff; color:' + tiny.toHexString() + '; }.whiteBg #mainNav.ddsmoothmenu ul li a { color: ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; cursor: pointer; }.greyBg #mainNav.ddsmoothmenu ul li a { color:' + tiny.toHexString() + '; cursor: pointer; } #tab03 - 2.darkBg ul.bxslider2.bxLeft { background- color: #002637; } #tab03- 2.darkBg ul.bxslider2.bxLeft: after { border- top: 500px solid ' + tiny.toHexString() + ';} #tab11 - 3.slick - dots li.slick - active button, #tab11 - 4.slick - dots li.slick - active button { background:' + tiny.toHexString() + ' !important; } #tab07 - 4.eaPlan { border: solid 1px ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; } #tab08 - 3.newsBtn a: hover { border: solid 1px ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; color: ' + tiny.toHexString() + '; } #tab03 - 4 ul.bxslider4.bxBg, #tab03 - 4 ul.bxslider4.slidePanel1, #tab03 - 4 ul.bxslider4.slidePanel2, #tab05 - 4.eaServ.servInner, #tab05 - 4.eaServ.servInner: hover, #tab09 - 2.inner, #tab09 - 3.inner, #tab09 - 4.inner { background:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; } #tab08 - 3.newsTitle, #tab08 - 4.newsTitle, #tab10 - 4.staffCon { background:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; color: #fff } #tab08 - 4.newsBtn a { background- color:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; color: #fff; } #tab09 - 4.homeImage: hover.inner { background:' + tiny.toRgbString() + '; }');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use style injection, add id's to div's and change its background color:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".picker").spectrum({
    color: "#ffd800",
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    showInput: true,
    change: function(color) {
      var tiny = tinycolor(color);
      color.getAlpha();
      color.setAlpha(0.8);
      color.getAlpha();              
      $('#palette-one-result').css({
        background: tiny.toRgbString()
      });              
    }
  });

  $(".picker2").spectrum({
    color: "#ffd800",
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    showInput: true,
    change: function(color) {
      var tiny = tinycolor(color);
      color.getAlpha();
      color.setAlpha(0.8);
      color.getAlpha();
       $('#palette-two-result').css({
        background: tiny.toRgbString()
      });         
    }

  });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x60dsvcu/)

Comment: I just though to add similar,:)) you have been faster.

Comment: char limit ----- ;)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my only issue is I need to add multiple styles so I need to inject the CSS, any ideas? I updated the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/yp0dx9ou/22/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/css/

`css({background: '...', border: '...'})`

Comment: What if the actual project has 50-60 styles... I just made the example basic

Comment: Assign it to class `testClass`, by id change `background` only. 

`<div id="palette-one-result" class="testClass">`

Comment: Sorry to take up more of your time but do you have a modified example of how to go about that.

Comment: `css({background: '...', border: '...'})` because it's mutable styles. Imagine that these styles is 50-60, then will declare variable `var styles = {...};` and use it `.css(styles);`. If you want to inject `style` tag you can set the `id` attribute to it, but this is incorrect approach, because it influences on a whole page.